# Add number of members to “Right Now” dashboard widget

Tags: users, dashboard, members

### Problem

I have this code in functions.php but it does not output the total number of members (something is wrong with it it breaks the site) in my "Right Now" dashboard. Is there a way to fix it?

```
function dashboard_wps_user_count() {
global $wpdb;
$users = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM $wpdb->users");
?>
<table>
<tbody>
   <tr class="first">
      <td class="first b b_pages"><a href="users.php"><? echo $users; ?></a></td>
      <td class="t pages"><a href="users.php">Members</a></td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
<?}
add_action( 'right_now_content_table_end', 'dashboard_wps_user_count');
```

### Additional feature

Also is there a way to show how many authors are registered and how many subscribers are registered also in the "Right now " dashboard?

Comment: provide the debug information, coz this code is working file with my local wordpress installation with 2010 theme installed

Comment: @amit  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end i have local setup also but something is off in this code i don't know why.

Comment: @amit removing this function removes the error! I placed it at the very end of the functions.php

Comment: try enclosing this code within `<?php` and `?>` and see if works.. Which theme you're using ?

Comment: @amit I use custom theme, where did You place the code? I placed it exactly like I wrote in functions.php and it gives out $end error <?php doesn't work either! Do You know any other way to do this?

Comment: I placed it at end of functions.php file.

Comment: my function.php starts like this: <?php ......

Comment: @amit I tried it on other installation of wp 3.4.1 and it shows the same $end error! I think the function is messed up!

Comment: so try putting that code before `?>` at the end,

Comment: oh well I did and it doesn't work so thanks for the try anyway. If You say it works for You great but it doesn't work for 2 of my wordpress local installations :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4357/discussion-between-amit-and-jimilesku)

Comment: @amit no matter ehwre I put the code it throws the $end error and gives me the bottom line as the one that is missing the $end. When I place ?> it still remains. WTF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is the small snippet to show total number of users and all roles with user count. This code should go in the themes `functions.php` file.

The code uses [`count_user`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/count_users) function to fetch the array and show it up on Right Now dashboard screen.

```
function wpse_60487_custom_right_now() {
    $users = count_users();
    echo '<table><tbody>';
    echo '<tr><td class="first b b_pages">'.$users['total_users'].'</td><td class="t pages"> total users</td></tr>';
    foreach($users['avail_roles'] as $role => $count)
    echo '<tr><td class="first b b_pages">'.$count.'</td><td class="t pages">'.$role.'</td></tr>';
    echo '</tbody></table>';

 }
add_action( 'wpse_60487_custom_right_now', 'dashboard_wps_user_count');
```